# simple python methods causing syntax errors

Tags: python

I have a simple python program with some math equations, that keep failing, and i don't know why.

```
def add(x, y):
    return(x + y)

def sub(x, y):
    return(x - y)


def multiply(x, y):
    return(x * y)

def divide(x, y):
    return(x / y)

def sqaure(x):
    return math.sqrt(x)
```

the error appears on the first line, when i define the add function

ERROR:

```
File "test.py", line 9
def add(x, y):
  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: i copy paste your code, i don't have any error

Comment: can you post your full code?

Comment: Particularly the 8 lines before line 9 are interesting. I suspect you forgot to close some parentheses there.

Comment: @schwobaseggl that is correct, i had forgotten to import math, and close a parentheses, thank you for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reviewed your code, and you may have some mistake before the function `add`.First let check the work code below:

```
import math

def add(x, y):
    return(x + y)

def sub(x, y):
    return(x - y)


def multiply(x, y):
    return(x * y)

def divide(x, y):
    return(x / y)

def sqaure(x):
    return math.sqrt(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(add(12, 34))
    print(sub(12, 34))
    print(multiply(12, 34))
    print(divide(12, 34))
    print(sqaure(16))
```

Now, if I add a somet mistake before the `add` function:

```
import math

(
def add(x, y):
    return(x + y)
```

And you can see something error like your paste:

```
(bitcoin)landpacks-MacBook-Pro:bitcoin-port frank$ python x.py    
File "x.py", line 4
     def add(x, y):
       ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, You'd better paste whole your code here instead of part.